# How to make column which is a list of values other columns in polars python

Tags: python-polars

I'm starting to use polars, so I have noob question.
I have a dataframe like this:

```
data = polars.DataFrame(
{
    "a": [1, 2, 3],
    "b": [4, 5, 6],
    "c": [7, 8, 9],
})
```

I want to make a column "d" which would be like this:

```
[1,4,7]
[2,5,8]
[3,6,9]
```

i.e. is a column of lists

As I understand `polars.col(['a', 'b', 'c'])` is not what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.concat_list()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.concat_list.html#polars-concat-list)

```
df.with_columns(
   d = pl.concat_list('a', 'b', 'c')
)
```

```
shape: (3, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬───────────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   ┆ d         │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---       │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ list[i64] │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═══════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 4   ┆ 7   ┆ [1, 4, 7] │
│ 2   ┆ 5   ┆ 8   ┆ [2, 5, 8] │
│ 3   ┆ 6   ┆ 9   ┆ [3, 6, 9] │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴───────────┘
```